# marshmallow & lollipop genymotion emulator not at all starting but all other emulator below api 21 are working in genymotion same system

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-6.0-marshmallow, genymotion

i have gone through different questions in stackoverflow regarding this topic and this is **not any spam question**

i am able to open all the emulators which are perfectly working but lollipop and marshmallow are not even starting in the same system at same time i have tried in different instances but no use

can any one explain me the reason why it is not working should i have to make any more changes so that both these versions work for me in genymotion

and i forgot to mention i have update virtual box and genymotion to the latest version also no use

Comment: what are your computer characteristics? CPU/GPU/OS ?

Comment: 4GB RAM,  500GB Hard Disk,  i7 processor, all the emulators are working except lollipop and marshmallow even intel HAXM is installed and is in running state tried every instance but no use